# simple where clause SSRS 2005 parameter not working

Tags: select, reporting-services

this should be a simple thing but I've spent hours to no avail.  Basically, I need to look up a salesrep # in a SQL database using the user's Window's user id.  The format of the user id is
"Norstar\kjones" and I need the "kjones" portion of it.

using the split function, I am able to pull just the 'kjones' part out:

```
split(User!UserID,"\").GetValue(1)
```

I've created a parameter called SlsmnNum and created a dataset to be used to look up the salesrep # using the user id (the slsm_num field is a varchar, not an integer):

```
select slsm_num from Salesman_Msid where slsm_msid = ''' + split(User!UserID,"\").GetValue(1) + '''
```

However, I get no results.  How can I get the select to work?

alternatively, I tried the following:
in parameter SlsmnNum, I set the default to an expression using:
`split(User!UserID,"\").GetValue(1)`   and this returns 'kjones', as expected.

I created a SECOND parameter (which is positioned BELOW the `SlsmnNum` parameter), `SlsmnNum2`, that has a default (and an available) value using a query, which is a dataset containing the following select statement:

```
select slsm_num from Salesman_Msid where slsm_msid = (@SlsmnNum)
```

When I run the query on the Data tab, when I type in 'kjones' into the parameter box, it returns '1366', the salesrep # I'm expecting.

But, when I Preview the report, all I get in `SlsmnNum2` box is `Select a Value` and nothing is there (it should return '1366').

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Try your first approach with **Query Text** as

```
="select slsm_num from Salesman_Msid where slsm_msid = '" & split(User!UserID,"\").GetValue(1) & "'"
```

[image]

Comment: Hi Anup, I tried this (and I think you meant it to be 'where slsm_msid = "'" + split(User!UserID,"\".GetValue(1) + "'"   ' -- the first ' needs to be in double qoutes like the last one, correct?) but am getting the error "Incorrect syntax near "!"".

Comment: Nope. I meant as it is showing in the code including the "=". It is more like a dynamic query.

Comment: oh -- so is this supposed to go in the expression field on the SlsmnNum parameter?

Comment: I'm confused on where your select statement is supposed to go -- if I put it in the dataset as the query, the quotes and = is not correct.  If I put it in the expression box on the SlsmnNum parameter, that whole line just shows up in the box on the Preview screen.  Where exactly is your code supposed to go?  thanks!

Comment: Added screenshot and updated code. My bad we need to use **&** not **+**.

Comment: ok, I created a new Dataset called SalesrepNumber and put exactly what you have (incl the quotes and "=" sign) in the query text field (my screen is different, I'm on 2005) and it puts it on the Data tab but the execute button (!) is greyed out so it's not syntactically ok.  When I go to parameter SlsrepNum, click "From Query" on default and choose my dataset SlsrepNum, there is no value to pick from in "Value Field". ?  I'm very new to SSRS, sorry for all the questions!